# Allow Cloud Service ARM template deployment to a different subscription than the keyVault

Tags: deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-cloud-services

Our KeyVault is in subscription 1 and we have multiple Cloud Services for multiple areas that we need deployed in different subscriptions. While working in Azdo I found out that I am unable to deploy CSES to a subscription that is different than the keyVault since the ARM template used for deployment is trying to access secrets from the keyvault.

Then, when I read this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/deploy-prerequisite, it states that the *"The key vault must be created in the same region and subscription as the cloud service"*.

Does anyone know of a way around this? It's imperative that we are able to deploy multiple Cloud Services (for different areas) in different Subscriptions and we only have one keyvault that stores all values used by the cloud services.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

***As mentioned in the [`Microsoft Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/deploy-prerequisite#key-vault-creation) that you have shared , its not possible as its a prerequisite to create Key vault in the same subscription as the cloud Services.***

***In this [`Github Issue`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/7650) , it is possible to use secrets from one subscription in another subscription but using certificates is an limitation in ARM templates.***

***It is recommended by Azure to use for different Key vault for different environments for using Certificates .***

***Secrets can be referenced as parameters in the ARM template to used by Azure Services but certificate can't be referenced from another subscriptions otherwise you will get the below error :***

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidParameter",
        "target": "sourceVault.id",
        "message": "The SubscriptionId:\"<id>\" of the request must match the SubscriptionId \"<sharedId>\" contained in the Key Vault Id."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, Cloud Services (extended support) does not have native support for cross-regional or cross-subscription key vault secret retrieval.

You can achieve much of the requested functionality by using [the official Key Vault extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/enable-key-vault-virtual-machine), though! The extension allows specification of secret uris that you want to refresh local certs from.

(Please keep in mind that sharing a single key vault across multiple services and regions is introducing a single point of architectural failure for your suite of services: If region A experiences a problem that makes your key vault unavailable, your services in many different regions and subscriptions may be negatively impacted even though their regions are perfectly healthy.)